# How can i reprocess it in order to get a well laid out csv file as in the pictures attached?

Tags: python, csv

I have this winequality-red csv file separated with semi columns and I would like to convert it into a proper.csv file in order to easily extract the attributes.A csv data separated with semi columns and it's so muddled up  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdco6.jpg)original csv data[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHecC.jpg) desired csv data

Answer (score 0):

You can just import it with `pandas` and re-export it.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', sep=';')
df.to_csv('your_file.csv')
```

Comment: You don't have permission to do edit files in this folder. That's not a problem with Python or the code.

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. __If you want to say "thank you," vote and accept that person's answer__. _READ: [What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)